# SetFillPattern using SVG with ability to change color of svg using fabricJS

Tags: svg, fabricjs, geometry

I am using fabric.js and I have the below issue.

I have added a circle on my canvas. now I want to fillpattern to the Circle with some SVG pattern image. And I want to change the color of the patter(SVG) dynamically.

I have tried below:

```
fabric.util.loadImage('../images/cross.svg', function (img) 
{ 
  newObj = img; 
  currentObject.setPatternFill({ source: img, repeat: 'repeat' }); 
  canvas.renderAll(); 
});
```

And Code is working fine for pattern filling in the circle. but I am not able to change the color of the svg.

Comment: show, till how much you did

Comment: fabric.util.loadImage('../images/cross.svg', function (img) {
                     newObj = img;
                     currentObject.setPatternFill({
                         source: img,
                         repeat: 'repeat'
                     });
                     canvas.renderAll();
                 });   //but i am not able to change the color of the pattern

Comment: are you able to make a svg image as fill pattern???

Comment: Yes, i am able to make svg as fill pattern. But i am not able to change color of the svg dynamically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [MCVE] example. I suggest reading [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also. Good Luck!